# Difference in variable between one obervation for a subject and the next (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, transform, panel, difference

In my panel dataset, I don't have the time needed for a specific activity, but only the time of starting an activity. That's why I need to make a sum out of the differences between the obervation after an activity and the actual observation.

That's why I now want to create a new variable in my panel dataset that specifies the difference in a variable between one obervation and the next. It gets clearer with an example dataset:

Example dataset:

```
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), level = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), activity = c("run","run","run","swim","swim","run","run","swim"), datesec = c(0,150,170,240,100,110,180,330))
> game_data
  player level activity datesec
1      1     1      run       0
2      1     1      run     150
3      1     2      run     170
4      1     2     swim     240
5      2     1     swim     100
6      2     1      run     110
7      2     2      run     180
8      2     2     swim     330
```

I now want to add a new variable for the sum of the time in seconds after each activity "run" to the next observation (It doesn't matter what the next activity is, whether "swim" or "run") and even if the next activity is in the next level, it should take the first activity of the next level to build the difference. I also only want to have one observation for each level for each user.

It should look like this:

```
game_data_new <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,2,2), level = c(1,2,1,2), n_run = c(2,1,1,1), n_swim = c(0,1,1,1), timeafterrun = c(170,70,70,150))
> game_data_new
  player level n_run n_swim timeafterrun
1      1     1     2      0          170
2      1     2     1      1           70
3      2     1     1      1           70
4      2     2     1      1          150
```

The 170 in the variable "timeafterrun" is for example computed by (150-0) + (170-150) 
Here, the code has to take the first observation of the next level,, level 2, because there is no further activity in level 1.

I've tried the following, but I don't know what to add to code to tell R that it should take the difference in datesec between the next obervation after "run" (even it's in the next level) and the actual "run".

```
game <- game %>%
  group_by(player,level) %>%
  summarize(
    n_run = sum(type == "run"),
    n_swim = sum(type == "swim"),
    timeafterrun = datesec(datesec of activity after_last_"run"-obervation) - datesec(actual_"run"-observation) 
  )
```

Comment: look at the functions `lag` and `lead` as well as `spread` and `gather`.

Comment: well, your question is unclear, you are trying to archive too many things at once. Try to break your problem into n steps. I believe this might be the first starting point. `game_data %>%
    group_by(player) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(diff_with_before_val = datesec - lag(datesec, default = 0))`

Comment: your code uses the column name `type` for what your example says is called `activity`. Just pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
game_data %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  mutate(nextdat=lead(datesec)) %>% 
  group_by(level, add=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(timeafterrun=max(nextdat,na.rm=TRUE)-min(datesec[activity=="run"],na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  summarize(n_run=sum(activity=="run"),n_swim=sum(activity=="swim"), timeafterrun=max(timeafterrun))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   player [?]
  player level n_run n_swim timeafterrun
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <int>        <dbl>
1      1     1     2      0          170
2      1     2     1      1           70
3      2     1     1      1           70
4      2     2     1      1          150
```

Here's what's going on: first, I create a helper column with the next (`lead`) datesec for each row (within an individual player).

Next I `group_by` both player and level, and create a column that subtracts the smallest datesec for lines with `activity=="run"` from the largest datesec in the group.

Then I `summarize` to create n_run and n_swim, and copy over timeafterrun, which should be the same for the entire group, so I arbitrarily picked `max`, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!